# Unable to view customer's order

Tags: magento2, orders, error, magento2.2.6, view

I have encountered an order view error. When I view an order in the magento2.2.6 background, it displays

> "Information Changes have been made to this section that
>   have not been saved. This tab contains invalid data. Please resolve
>   this before saving."

Instead of order details. 
I found some of the same problems on Google. I disabled `Temando_Shipping` modules according to their solution, but it didn't solve my problem, I still can't view this order.
And I don't see the error log related to this problem.
Can someone help me?

Comment: For debugging purposes first disable all custom modules one by one, and after disabling each custom module, run **`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`** command.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora I found the cause of this error, I think it is not a module problem. All the orders that can not be opened have the same product, I deleted the product yesterday, I don't know why deleting the product will cause this error, how should it be solved? And I ran this command php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Run this :

- `php bin/magento module:disable Temando_Shipping --clear-static-content`
- `rm -rf generated/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*`
- `php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:di:compile && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Comment: @YIgen Guxholli I ran these commands, but it didn't work. I found the cause of this error, I think it is not a module problem. All the orders that can not be opened have the same product, I deleted the product yesterday, I don't know why deleting the product will cause this error, how should it be solved?

Comment: @yoyo Check if the product is disabled , or has an error while accessing it , but mostly check if it is disabled/outofstock

Comment: @YIgen Guxholli I deleted a few products, not disabled. I can't view the order when the previous order contains the product I deleted. I don't know what I should do to see the order.

Comment: @yoyo than go and do a full reindex *php bin/magento indexer:reindex* , try again and let me know

Comment: @YIgen Guxholli https://prnt.sc/o1qn7v, Still useless

Comment: How did you deleted the products ?

Comment: Backstage product management page select product to delete

Comment: See if the products you deleted are in the order in database (if you deleted the product from admin that doesnt mean that the order will show error since the product stays in database) , work locally on developer mode to see the logs, check for any code recently added if you forgot any tags / namespace , disable custom modules that relates to order edit .